# Jenkins: Start of windows SSH slave times out

Tags: ssh, jenkins

OK, I have a Jenkins Master on CentOS and  I use it to run a bunch of windows slaves with installed java services and that runs flawless. Now I have a new windows server in DMZ so I cannot use the Java webstart. I have installed Cygwin SSH on the server and I can use SSH to connect to it with Putty, so that end seems to work.

In Jenkins I have installed SSH Plugin, SSH Slave plugin and SSH Credentials plugin.
Remote FS-root is: "C:\jenkins" (as I read somewhere)
Launch method is: "Launch slave agents on unix machines with SSH"
Host: dmz-address.domain
Credentials: Global cred with User password. (the credentials that works with putty)

I cannot see a log and in the node list there is just a message that there was a time out.
So even if I can reach the slave with SSH, Jenkins cannot and I suspect that I have missed something.

Comment: Sometimes these problems are related to user permissions or identities.  Make sure you manually test things as the same user that Jenkins runs as.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that and I logged in on the Master as the Jenkins user and used ssh and sftp to connect to the slave. That worked.